# How to reverse proxy assets from another unsecured website?

Tags: nginx, proxypass, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have this situation. Current VM where this nginx config is stored has a valid ssl certificate. Inside this VM is the main application `app1` served in port 80. On another port 1234 another service is served `app2` in a docker container. I managed to reverse proxy `app2` like this

```
       location /app2/ {
           proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:1234/;

           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
           proxy_read_timeout 600s;

           proxy_redirect    http://127.0.0.1:3888/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/vnc/;
           proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
           proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
       }
```

`app2` can be accessed by https://mywebsite.com/app2

Now I have a Laravel app in another VM `app3` (not in a docker container). I did the same procedure. When I go to https://websited.com/app3 it only loads the html part but not javascript and css. The error on mozilla console shows as

```
Blocked loading mixed active content “http://mywebsite.com/css/style.css”
```

As I understand it should look inside the resources of the VM that `app3` is stored.
How do I make the nginx to load `app3` resources like js and css?

Comment: You mention `mywebsite.com/app2` and `websited/app3`. Can you clarify what are the exact sites here? Also, if you could provide the output of `nginx -T` in the question, that would be helpful in seeing the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the root URL in your Laravel application, so that Laravel generates the correct URLs for the resources it refers to.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35304448/laravel-change-base-url has information how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it still search within current VM for the styling files and javascript.